# The question is to evaluate the limit, where [•] denotes the greatest integer function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\log_e x^n)-\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}$$

I tried separating the two functions in the numerator but then I get stuck up with the greatest integer part.

Comment: When $x$ is near zero (say 0.01), what is the value of $[x]$?

Comment: HInt: Separate it for $n$ odd , even  and $x\to 0^+ ,x\to 0^-$

Comment: Hint: Is the logarithm defined for $x<0$?  Or perhaps only sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $y=x^n$ isn't defined for $x<0$.

Thus, we'll only discuss the case when $x>0$.

Since greatest integer of any number $\in (0,1)=0$. Hence, $\lfloor x \rfloor$, when $x\to 0^+$ is equal to $0$.

Thus \begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\log_e x^n)-\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\log_e x^n)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{n (\log_e x)}{x}\\
&=n \cdot \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\log_e x)}{x}\to n \cdot -\infty \to -\infty
\end{align}

Thus, the limit doesn't exist.